# Install node-sass on plesk

Tags: node.js, plesk, node-sass

Ive been looking online for a solution to installing node-sass on my plesk server. I read that this is kind of a no no as this should not be done on a production server(dont care - not a live site).

I have uploaded the documents via bitbucket and click the NPM install button. The result is the failure below:

```
3822 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.12.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
3822 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
3822 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/plesk/node/9/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
3822 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
3822 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
3822 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
3823 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.12.0
3824 verbose cwd /var/www/vhosts/mjmnagy.info/app
3825 verbose Linux 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
3826 verbose argv "/opt/plesk/node/9/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/9/bin/npm" "install"
3827 verbose node v9.10.1
3828 verbose npm  v5.6.0
3829 error file sh
3830 error code ELIFECYCLE
3831 error errno ENOENT
3832 error syscall spawn
3833 error node-sass@4.12.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
3833 error spawn ENOENT
3834 error Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 install script.
3834 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3835 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I attempted to login to the server using SSH but for the life of me couldn't figure out how to install it.

Using SSH,  i navigated to where node is install (`/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/`) trying 6/7/8 and then running npm. i always got unrecognized command.

I then realized that the version i have of node-sass was higher than the node version install on the server(`9.10.1`)

What do i need to do to be able to install the module?

Answer (score 0):

ignore plesks NPM install button and create a script in your package.json

`"installme": "npm i --unsafe-perms"`

Using plesk run the script

`installme --scripts-node-prepend-path`

Comment: I got this error afte runing this command. "/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory"