# How to install npm packages on plesk?

Tags: node.js, npm, plesk

I wanted to install node-apk-parser:https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-apk-parser into my node js project.It works locally if I run npm install on my VS package manager console. But when I update the package.json on Plesk and hit the button Npm Install and I run my website domain it says "**Module not found error for node apk parser**"?Node apk parser is at the last.
This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-express-mysql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js Restful CRUD API with Node.js, Express and MySQL",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "express",
    "express-fileupload",
    "mysql",
    "restapi"
  ],
  "author": "bezkoder",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5"
  },
  "node-apk-parser": {
    "version": "0.2.3",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-apk-parser/-/node-apk-parser-0.2.3.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha1-OFoUGm2jjeVi5dnwiWG/lyTTX8Q=",
    "requires": {
      "adm-zip": "~0.4.4",
      "debug": "~0.7.4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why dont you add it as dependency?

Comment: will this help https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/

Comment: @Estradiaz How to do that?Sorry a bit new to Plesk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write my own script in package.json and run script instead. Referred to this question:[Install node-sass on plesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265869/install-node-sass-on-plesk)